# Grant the server the permission of creating a folder

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, file-permissions, fs, file-access

I have a Ubuntu Server on DigitalOcean, which hosts some websites. I just built a `mean.js` stack app on my mac, and I plan to deploy it to production, thus to this existing server.

I followed [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-mean-js-stack-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) to install `node.js` and `mongodb`, etc. Then, rather than cloning the sample app of `mean.js`, I cloned my own app from the github:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/softtimur/myapp.git /opt/myapp
cd /opt/myapp
sudo mkdir public/tmp/
sudo npm install
npm start
```

Then, in a browser, I entered `https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000/#/new`. On the server side, I got an error:

```
router.post /mkdir
{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 'public/tmp/sAlTI6NDo5NQcO-lAAAA/'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: 'public/tmp/sAlTI6NDo5NQcO-lAAAA/' }
```

This is because in the backend of my app, it tries to create a folder in `public/tmp/` by `fs.mkdir(...)` where `fs = require('fs')`.

So does anyone know to how to give the server this permission?

**PS:** I also tried to run

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you created `public/tmp/` as root:

```
sudo mkdir public/tmp/
```

But you're running the app as `$USER`, which will most likely not be allowed to write to that directory.

To fix:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP public/tmp/
```